# Execute validation with button

Tags: handsontable

I'm looking to execute the Handsontable validation on the click of a button instead of on cell change. Something like this: `validateCells()` (return bool `isValid`). This function doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
var
data = [],
container = document.getElementById('hot-Handsontable'),
save = document.getElementById('save'),
hidden = document.getElementById('hot-Handsontable-value'),
hot,
hotIsValid = true,
emailValidator;

emptyValidator = function(value, callback) {
  callback(false);
};

hot = Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  minRows: 1,
  minCols: 21,
  maxCols: 21,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  stretchH: 'all',
  colHeaders: ['Test'],
  columns: [{data:'Test',allowInvalid:true, validator: emptyValidator}]
});

// exclude empty rows from validation
$('.title-block .united-alert a[href^=#Handsontable]').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var row = href.getIdIndex();
  var prop = /([^__]*)$/.exec(href)[0];

  hot.selectCellByProp(parseInt(row), prop);
  return false;
});

// Save event
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function(e) {
  var test = hot.validateCells(); // test is undefined

  if (hotIsValid === true) {
    hidden.value = JSON.stringify(hot.getData());
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please expand on what you mean by "not working" and show us some of your code? How do you call `validateCells()`? How do you know it "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors on your console? Have you tried logging some of the behavior?

Comment: I've setup a listener and want only to process the validation on click of the save button

`code Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function(e) {
var isValid = validateCells();
if (!isValid) {
e.preventDefault();
}
});`

Comment: Alright, again, it would be nice if you showed us more of your code but straight up `validateCells()` is not a global function that I don't see how that would ever work. You have to call it on the instance of your handsontable object. Something like `hotInstance.validateCells()`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed. It is now hot.validateCells() and I added my code above

Comment: Ok, how do you know it's not validating? The definition of `validateCells()` states that it takes a callback function but does not return anything. So `test` is correctly set to undefined. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing, instead of `var test = hot.validateCells()` is the following:

```
// Save event
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function(e) {
  hot.validateCells(function(hotIsValid) {
    if (hotIsValid === true) {
      hidden.value = JSON.stringify(hot.getData());
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
});
```

Notice that `validateCells` takes a callback and returns `undefined`. This is why you see `test` as `undefined`. One other thing to note is that the callback is executed for every cell in your table so be careful with it.